# Writing a Prolog Rule

Tags: prolog, rule

Given that I have entered

```
maindish(thanksgiving, turkey). 
sidedish(thanksgiving,pie).
```

into the factbase, I am supposed to write a   rule called  `meal(Holiday, Food)` – that will identify the type of food served on a given holiday.   For example, if  asked about thanksgiving, it will return turkey and pie as the    options. So far I have:

```
meal(Holiday, Food):- maindish(Holiday,Food), sidedish(Holiday,Food).
write('For the holiday:'), write(Holiday),write('the meal(s)are:'), write(Food),nl.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
meal(Holiday, [F1,F2]) :- maindish(Holiday,F1), sidedish(Holiday,F2).

?- meal(thanksgiving, Foods).
```

although modelling fixed structure data with lists is not optimal.